# VBA Recursive folder function is missing particular subfolders

Tags: vba, excel, recursion, directory

I'm trying to create a recursive function which adds each folder (and subfolders) to a collection of custom objects.  My code is working for around 75% of the folders / subfolders but seemingly random ones are being missed from the collection.

Any ideas?

FolderObj is a custom class, the collection I'm adding to is called ToPathList

```
Option Explicit

Sub RecurseFolderList(Foldername As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim FSO, NextFolder
    Dim OriginalRange As Range
    Dim tempFolderObj As FolderObj
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Err.Number > 0 Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(Foldername) Then

        Set NextFolder = FSO.GetFolder(Foldername)
        Set FolderArray = NextFolder.subfolders

        For Each NextFolder In FolderArray

            Set tempFolderObj = New FolderObj

            'assign variables to temporary object
            With tempFolderObj
                .ID = i
                .Filename = NextFolder.Name
                .path = NextFolder.path
                .first3ints = first3Non0Ints(NextFolder.Name)
            End With

            'add temporary object to colelction
            Call ToPathList.Add(tempFolderObj, CStr(i))

            i = i + 1

            RecurseFolderList (NextFolder)

        Next

'        Set NextFolder = Nothing
'        Set FolderArray = Nothing

    End If

    Set FSO = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of `On Error Resume Next` then you will likely see where your error lies

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Removing that didn't help but I've figured out the problem.

My key (i) was declared inside the function and therefore was being reset to '1' every time the function was called.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

My key (i) was declared inside the function and therefore was being reset to '1' every time the function was recursed.

This resulted in non-unique keys and therefore some items were not being added to the collection.

Thanks to everyone for their help.